# opencvのCountNonZeroについて

Tags: python, opencv

opencvのCountNonZeroを用いた下記のプログラム

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import cv2
import numpy as np

w_num = 0

img = cv2.imread("detect_0_0.jpg")
w_num = cv2.CountNonZero(img)
print("%d"%w_num)
```

を実行したところ

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wcount2.py", line 9, in <module>
    w_num = cv2.cv.CountNonZero(img)
TypeError: CvArr argument 'arr' must be IplImage, CvMat or CvMatND. Use 
fromarray() to convert numpy arrays to CvMat or cvMatND
```

というエラーが出てきました。これを処理するにはどうしたらよいのでしょうか。
プログラム言語はpythonです。

Comment: @mjy  実はこのプログラムの入力した画像がもう白黒画像になっているのですが、それでも一度入力画像をグレースケール変換した方がよろしいのでしょうか？

Comment: 質問のコードにはタイポがあります。そして、`CountNonZero` を `countNonZero` に直したとしても、質問のようなエラーにはなりません。たぶんチャンネル数がらみのエラーが出ると思いますので、それを前提として回答しました。

Answer (score 3):

`countNonZero()` の引数は [*"single-channel array"* との事](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gaa4b89393263bb4d604e0fe5986723914)です。
`imread` で読み込んだ場合、デフォルトでは三色（BGR）のチャンネルを持つようです。

シングルチャンネルの `array` を得るには、例えば以下のような方法が考えられます。
（リンク先は OpenCV のドキュメントですが Python 向けの記述は無いですね。引数の順番などは少し違う場合があります）

#### [`imread`](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56) で画像を読み込む際に[`ImreadModes`](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga61d9b0126a3e57d9277ac48327799c80) を指定する

```
img = cv2.imread("test.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
w_num = cv2.countNonZero(img)
```

#### [`cvtColor`](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga397ae87e1288a81d2363b61574eb8cab)で変換する

```
img = cv2.imread("test.png")
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
w_num = cv2.countNonZero(img_gray)
```

#### [`split`](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga8027f9deee1e42716be8039e5863fbd9) でチャンネルを一つ取り出す

特定の色だけ処理する事になりますが、元々がグレースケール画像や2値画像であれば上の方法と同じ結果になるはずです。

```
img = cv2.imread("test.png")
img_ch0 = cv2.split(img)[0]
w_num = cv2.countNonZero(img_ch0)
```

Comment: チャンネルの数が関係していたのですね...   ありがとうございます。試してみます。